# Couldn't consume values inside React context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem to set the user in my web page. I used `AppContext` where all the components to update the states are. When I run my code, it says that `setUser` is `undefined`, but I defined it in `AppContext` and imported it in `App.jsx`. Anyone can help? I saw others solution and it seems that

```
const { setUser } = useContext(AppContext);
```

have to be out of the component, but shows this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'setUser' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
App
D:/ELEARNING/PROYECTS/PROYECT-ANDREA/store-lopez-andrea/src/App.js:11
   8 | import { Router } from "./routers/Router";
   9 | 
  10 | function App() {
> 11 |   const { setUser } = useContext(AppContext);
  12 |   useEffect(() => {
  13 |     getUser().then((user) => {
  14 |       setUser(user);
```

This is App.jsx:

```
import "./App.css";
import { Header } from "./components/header/Header";
import { Nav } from "./components/nav/Nav.jsx";
import { getUser } from "./services/users";
import { AppContext } from "./context/AppContext";
import { Notification } from "./components/notification/Notification";
import { Router } from "./routers/Router";

function App() {
  const { setUser } = useContext(AppContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser().then((user) => {
      setUser(user);
    });
  }, [setUser]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Notification />
      <Nav />
      <Header />
      <Router />
      <AppContext />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is AppContext.jsx:

```
import React,{ useState } from "react";
 import { usePagination } from "../components/utils/pagination.jsx";


export const AppContext = React.createContext();


export default function AppProvider({ children }) {
    const [user,setUser] = useState({})
    const [points, setPoints] = useState(0)
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [reedemStatus, setReedemStatus] = useState({})
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([])


    const paginationList = usePagination(products, 16)
    const paginationHistoryList = usePagination(history, 16)

    const totalProducts = products.length
    const totalHistory = history.length

    const handlerAddPoint =(value)=>{
        const newUser = {...user}
        newUser.points = user.points + value
        setUser(newUser)
      }
    
      const handlerSubtractPoint =(points)=>{
        const newUser = {...user}
        newUser.points = user.points - points
        setUser(newUser)
      }
    return(
        <AppContext.Provider value={{user,
            setUser,  
            handlerAddPoint, 
            handlerSubtractPoint, 
            points,
            setPoints,  
            products, 
            setProducts, 
            totalProducts,
            paginationList,
            reedemStatus, 
            setReedemStatus,
            history,
             setHistory, 
             paginationHistoryList,
             totalHistory}}>
             {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

In Users.jsx I have the "getUser" component

```
import {BASE_URL, headers} from "./constant"

export const getUser = async()=>{
    try{
        const response= await fetch(BASE_URL+"user/me",{headers})
        const data = await response.json()
        return data
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than "it says that setUser is undefine[d]", please [show the full error you get](/help/how-to-ask). Just copy-paste it, with some code markup, into your post (not as an "edit: ..." but just as part of  your post, breaking up your first paragraph)

Comment: On what line do you get a "*TypeError: `Cannot destructure property 'setUser' of 'Object(...)(...)'`*"? None of the code you posted does use `Object(…)`

Comment: Can you show us how you render the `<App>` and how/where you use the `<AppProvider>`, please?

Comment: `<AppContext />` makes no sense, it's a context not a component

Comment: @yousoumar's deleted answer is correct. you're trying to access context in a component that is higher up in the tree than your context provider

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , thank you. Now I have posted the error.

Comment: @Bergi, line 11 App,jsx

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variables and functions in your `context` only within components embedded in your `provider`. In order to achieve what you want, menage to put your `App` component in `AppProvider`. You can for example do it like so in your `index` file:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider> 
      <App /> 
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And you don't need to have `<AppContext />` in your `return`.

Comment: Do you mean `<AppProvider>` instead of `<AppContext>`?

Comment: My bad, yeah I was talking about AppProvider. I am gonna fix my answer.

Comment: And you don't need to have `<AppContext />` in your `return`.